# How are fiber bundles with a homogeneous space fiber called?

Tags: reference-request, fiber-bundles, homogeneous-spaces

Let $\pi:M\to N$ be a fiber bundle with typical fiber $F\cong G/H$ for some Lie group $G$ and isotropy group $H$, such that the automorphisms of $F$ are $G$-equivariant diffeomorphisms.

Do these bundles have a name? I can't find it in the literature and this makes it hard to find results about such spaces.

Comment: I don't think there is a name for those.

Comment: When you say "automorphisms" do you mean "structure group"? In any case, I'm not aware of a shorter name than "fiber bundles with fiber $F$ and structure group..."

Comment: Yes, I meant the structure group. Now at least I'm quite sure that there is no particular name for them. Thanks